# Rails factory girl create factory in callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I have the following setup. A car is linked to a loan and a loan needs to be assigned to a car. The business logic dictates that a car shall not exists without a loan. So i set the foreign key to `null: false`. 
Now i have a hard time setting up the test environment straight.
The problem is the `after create` callback. I would like to create after each time a car is created to automatically create also the loan. But i am stuck assigning the car id to the loan.

The syntax i use below results in an error. Every help appreciated

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one loan
end
class Loan < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to car
end

spec/factories.rb
factory :car
 model Faker::GameOfThromes.house
 manufactoring_plant Faker::StarWars.planet
 after(:create) do |car|
  create :loan, car_id: car.id #error
  # car.create_loan 
 end
end


factory :loan
 initial_amount Faker::Number.number(5)
 start_date Faker::Date.backward(15)
 stop_date Date.tomorrow
 installment_amount 1000
end
```

*Update*

When i use the `factory girl associations` i get the `PG::NotNullViolation error`

```
factory :car
 model Faker::GameOfThromes.house
 manufactoring_plant Faker::StarWars.planet
 loan
end
```

results in

```
An error occurred in a `before(:suite)` hook.
Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.lint

FactoryGirl::InvalidFactoryError:
 The following factories are invalid:

 * car - PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "car_id" violates not-null constraint
 DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, 1453, null, 2016-11-04 10:29:05.4881, 2016-11-04 10:29:05.4881, 2016-11-04, 2000-01-01, null, null, 9588, 1162, ).
 : INSERT INTO "loans" ("start_date", "stop_date", "initial_amount",  "installment_amount", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5,  $7) RETURNING "id" (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
 * loan - PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "car_id" violates not-null constraint
 DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, 1453, null, 2016-11-04 10:29:05.49128, 2016-11-04 10:29:05.49128, 2016-11-04, 2000-01-01, null, null, 9588, 1162, 0, f).
```

The foreign keys have all standard names e.g. `car_id`,  why is `factory girl` no able to create the association?

Comment: Hm... have you tried `after :create do |car|; create(:loan, car: car);end` ?

Comment: Hey Steve, yes i tried that. This works nice except that one loan is created which is not linked to a car. So for each car i create a loan with the correct fk setup, but the default (?) build strategy builds every factory defined in `factories.rb` once. So also one`loan` which then fails because this is not linked to a car. My work around now is to remove the loan factory and in the after create use the ActiveRecord create method for loans instead, this is not so nice but working. Do you know by any chance how to stop a loan factory being build without a car ?